# How can I still be able to toggle during the animation effect in queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#menu').click(function(){
    $('#nav_bar').slideToggle(400).delay(12000).fadeOut(600);
});
```

I need to slideDown the #nav_bar and stop the fadeOut effect and vice versa be able to slideUp the #nav_bar during the delay.

Any idea?

I tried to use stop() without any luck.

Thanks

jsfidde: https://jsfiddle.net/ex9wL6g0/

Comment: can you provide the html as well?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that if you call [`clearQueue()`](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) before the `slideToggle()`, it may stops the `.delay()` before sliding up.

Comment: Yes, it works pretty well. Can you give me an answer so I can accept that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `clearQueue()`:

```
$('#menu').click(function(){
  $('#nav_bar').clearQueue().slideToggle(400).delay(12000).fadeOut(600);
});
```